# Email functionality is not working in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I tried lot of options in last two days but none of them is working for me:

I was having google apps account on my primary domain and it was not working so I tried SMTP pro somehow but that also has not worked. So I uninstalled the same and tried to have email hosting on my subdomain (where Magento is installed). So my email looks like support@shop.xxxx.in and it is same server where hosting is. Hoping it would serve the purpose, but it is not.

So I thought cronjob might be the problem so I configured the same in my cpanel for every five min. however, it was there in magento already.

I also tried to send forgot password email if it works but it didn't. So I understand it is something configuration related, now I have this from exception log:

```
2016-10-14T17:54:14+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail. ' in /home/trishstm/public_html/shop/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php:137
Stack trace:
#0 /home/trishstm/public_html/shop/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail->_sendMail()
#1 /home/trishstm/public_html/shop/lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#2 /home/trishstm/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(455): Zend_Mail->send()
#3 /home/trishstm/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(507): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->send(Array, Array, Array)
#4 /home/trishstm/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php(79): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('customer_passwo...', 'support', Array, Array, Array, '1')
#5 /home/trishstm/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php(676): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer->send()
#6 /home/trishstm/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php(693): Mage_Customer_Model_Customer->_sendEmailTemplate('customer/passwo...', 'customer/passwo...', Array, '1')
#7 /home/trishstm/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(715): Mage_Customer_Model_Customer->sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail()
#8 /home/trishstm/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Customer_AccountController->forgotPasswordPostAction()
#9 /home/trishstm/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('forgotpasswordp...')
#10 /home/trishstm/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 /home/trishstm/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#12 /home/trishstm/public_html/shop/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 /home/trishstm/public_html/shop/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#14 {main}
```

But completely unable to understand where the problem is. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Try to check if sendmail is correctly installed or postfix on your server. Check server  log also

Answer (score 0):

You have to install SMTP Pro extension. [SMTP Pro Extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html)

Test email check from SMTP Pro extension configuration after add gmail account user name and password.

If some validation show on test email, you have to get more information from SMTP Pro setting guide.

If all settings are validated then you have to set store email address for sent email account for from email address.

Now you can check test email by forgot password store account.

Let me know if you have any problem from above.

Comment: I already tested this, tried all the combinations in SMTP pro to get it done but none of them have worked.

Comment: what you say from the log should be the error.

Comment: You have added gmail account or else ?

Comment: Also you have to try first test email with simple php code, check for email working or not ?

Comment: it was google apps for business my website is something like shop.xxxx.in and email was support@xxxx.in on google apps. But now it is different. I am using email service of that subdomain like support@shop.xxxx.in

Comment: use your gmail account for it. for just testing purpose.

Comment: I think my SMTP pro was not installed properly, It was done manually, check this log:

Comment: SMTP pro extension installed from magento connect or manually ?

Comment: manually, as my magento connect is not working and that is a separate issue. I am .net programmer so all understand is programming and not php.

Comment: add screen shot of your SMTP Pro admin configuration in your question,

Comment: sorry, I uninstalled it so dont have now, have to install it back.

Comment: the point is when I was trying the testrun in smtp pro, it was just refreshing the page or nothing else happens, no error message.

Comment: reinstall and check again.

Comment: ok, i will try, but I have to install it manually, kindly confirm the source which is best for magento 1.9 and also should I try with google apps or localhost?

Comment: You can download magento extension,  override app folder to your project. check it in admin. you have test it with gmail account on server not in local system.

Comment: I downloaded from the author's website. I hope that will work.

Comment: If you have Mandrill enabled you should disable it

Comment: where iI can find mandrill